# Internal error when setting up cache

Tags: fat-free-framework

Im trying to set the cache for my app.
My problem is that I get error 500 when Im trying to use it.
This is my code:

```
<?php


include_once '/var/www/libs/mainCache/fatfree-master/lib/base.php';

class CacheManager
{
    private $cache;
    private $isDebug;

    const GYM_LIST = "gym_list";
    const CHALLENGES_LIST = "challnges_list";


    function __construct($isDebug = false)
    {
        $this->cache = \Cache::instance();
        $this->isDebug = $isDebug;
        $folder = $this->isDebug ? "/var/www/soFitTest/cache/" : "/var/www/soFit/cache/";
        $this->cache->load(true, "folder=".$folder);
    }

    public function exists($id)
    {
        return $this->cache->exists($id);
    }

     public function set($id, $value)
    {
        return $this->cache->set($id, $value);
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        return $this->cache->get($id);
    }

     public function clear($id)
    {
        return $this->cache->clear($id);
    }


}
```

When I run my code:

```
$cacheManager = new CacheManager(true);

$gmyList = $cacheManager->get(CacheManager::GYM_LIST);

            if($gmyList)
            {
                $result = $gmyList;
                $result["cache"] = "true";
            }
            else
            {
            $result = $gymManager->getGymsList();
            $result["cache"] = "false";
            $cacheManager->set(CacheManager::GYM_LIST, $result);
            }
```

I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
        <style>code{word-wrap:break-word;color:black}.comment,.doc_comment,.ml_comment{color:dimgray;font-style:italic}.variable{color:blueviolet}.const,.constant_encapsed_string,.class_c,.dir,.file,.func_c,.halt_compiler,.line,.method_c,.lnumber,.dnumber{color:crimson}.string,.and_equal,.boolean_and,.boolean_or,.concat_equal,.dec,.div_equal,.inc,.is_equal,.is_greater_or_equal,.is_identical,.is_not_equal,.is_not_identical,.is_smaller_or_equal,.logical_and,.logical_or,.logical_xor,.minus_equal,.mod_equal,.mul_equal,.ns_c,.ns_separator,.or_equal,.plus_equal,.sl,.sl_equal,.sr,.sr_equal,.xor_equal,.start_heredoc,.end_heredoc,.object_operator,.paamayim_nekudotayim{color:black}.abstract,.array,.array_cast,.as,.break,.case,.catch,.class,.clone,.continue,.declare,.default,.do,.echo,.else,.elseif,.empty.enddeclare,.endfor,.endforach,.endif,.endswitch,.endwhile,.eval,.exit,.extends,.final,.for,.foreach,.function,.global,.goto,.if,.implements,.include,.include_once,.instanceof,.interface,.isset,.list,.namespace,.new,.print,.private,.public,.protected,.require,.require_once,.return,.static,.switch,.throw,.try,.unset,.use,.var,.while{color:royalblue}.open_tag,.open_tag_with_echo,.close_tag{color:orange}.ini_section{color:black}.ini_key{color:royalblue}.ini_value{color:crimson}.xml_tag{color:dodgerblue}.xml_attr{color:blueviolet}.xml_data{color:red}.section{color:black}.directive{color:blue}.data{color:dimgray}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
        <p>mkdir(): Permission denied</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My folder is set to full permissions:

[image]

Comment: You might want to create the following two folders as well: `cache` and `tmp`

Comment: The cache->load method only gas 1 parameter... Your true parameter is superfluous. Just drop it and just use one string value